# DynamoDB LSI or GSI to query on composite attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to use DynamoDB for my JAVA project and I have this (from my point of view) strange scenario that I have to cover. Let me to explain how I organize my table:

Suppose that I have to store these info related to Books:

- `book_id` (UUID) used as PK autogerated
- `author_id` (UUID)
- `type` (String)
- `book_code` (UUID) this different as concept from book_id
- `publishing_house_id` (String)
- `book_gender` (String)

And additional dynamic attributes that are not queryable and I'm thinking to store as Document (JSON)

Now, the queries that I need are:

1. Insert/Get/Update/Delete book by book_id
2. Get all book by `author_id`
3. Get all book by `author_id and type`
4. Get book by `book_code, publishing_house_id, book_gender` (I would like to highlight that this tuple will be unique)

- Using the book_id as PK I'll be able to cover the first query set (CRUD using the book id)
- For the query #2 and #3 the idea is to create a GS index where the author_id is the PK and type is the SK.

In order to cover the query #4 I'm thinking to:

- Create an dedicated Attribute book_sk where I'll store:
  book_gender#publishing_house_id#book_code
- Create a Local Secondary Index  using this book_sk as SK
- Probably I can move book_code, publishing_house_id, book_gender into a Document field instead to have these unquerable attributes here.

I'm not very sure about this design.

What do you think?

In that case, is it better to use a LSI or GSI for the query #4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #4, if you're always getting a book by those three together, then make an attribute with that concatenated value and use it as the PK of a GSI, making it easy to directly look up.

Comment: Well, thanks. So, for this scenario it’s better to use a GSI …. I was pretty sure that the usage of a LSI was better…. I have to understand/find again a real/possibile usage of it… when is it better to usge a LSI instead of a GSI?

Comment: Don’t use an LSI unless an experienced DynamoDB user says to. They give you the benefit of strong consistency but hurt scalability.